# Determining an integer value based off dates?

Tags: php, date

Unfortunately, I have not been able to setup XDebug on my Windows machine / IIS in order to debug my PHP, so that's making things very difficult.

Anyways, I'm running a phpBB forum and I'm trying to import data from a collection of CSV files which contain threads / posts. A sample file might look like this:

```
A||N||1||username||Topic Title||||1
Z||000000||username||01-06-2017||03:30 PM||original post body
Z||000001||anotherUsername||01-06-2017||03:42 PM||response post body
```

**Note:** MM/DD/YYYY format, not DD/MM/YYYY.

I have 5 "Active" forums, and then 5 "Archive" forums. **Depending on the date** of the last message posted in any given thread, I want to copy this thread either to one of the 5 Active forums, or 5 Archive forums. I have this code:

```
//Get file data for specific file
$fileContents = file($filename);

//Then split the data into an array
$explosion = explode("||", $fileContents[$i]);

//some logic to determine $forum_id for which Archive forum to insert the thread into, based on the directory containing $filename.

$postedDate = new DateTime(str_replace("-", "/", $explosion[3]));
$strCutoff = "2015-10-01";
$dtCutoff = strtotime($strCutoff);

//If the post was created before 10/01/15, insert into archive forum.
//This means the current $forum_id determined above is accurate
$isArchiveThread = ($postedDate < $dtCutoff);

//If the post is NOT to be archived (aka, if it is ACTIVE), determine the new $forum_id
if ($isArchiveThread === false)
    $forum_id = $forum_id - 7; //Active ForumID = Archive ForumID minus 7.
```

`$explosion` contains the data from any given line **other than** the first line. `$explosion[3]` contains the date.

Previous business logic dictated that any threads more than 1 year old should not be imported at all. In which case, I was comparing `$postedDate` to `date()` and then checking the number of years between the two dates. If it was greater than or equal to 1, skip the insertion process and immediately move on to the new file. The old logic worked fine; it was only inserting threads created within the last year from all of my files. But since updating the code for the new business logic, it is not behaving correctly.

The sample file I provided above, for example, is being inserted into the Archive forum, even though it was created / most recent post was made **after** 2015/10/01.

I'm sure I must be doing something dumb, but without being able to actually step through my code I'm not sure what's wrong. It seems to me like my last `if` statement must not be evaluating as I expect it to.

**EDIT**: Added the following lines of code;

```
echo $dtCutoff . "<BR>";
echo $isArchiveThread;
```

Just after I determine `$isArchiveThread`'s value.

The output I get this:

> [phpBB Debug] PHP Notice: in file [ROOT]/includes/functions_test.php on line 196: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int
>    1443657600
>
> 1

It repeats those `[phpBB Debug] and`144367600`lines **57** times, and then prints the`1` only once.

I added a few lines to make my code only attempt to read the first 30 files just so I could see the ouput... So if it's only looping 30 times, I'm not sure why I get 115 lines of output (57 * 2 + 1).

Comment: did you echo the `($postedDate < $dtCutoff)` result? is it true or false?
in either way, the values of this equitation should show you what is wrong right?

Comment: First of all, please try with `$dtCutoff = new DateTime($strCutoff);`

Comment: Editted my post with output for `$dtCutoff` and `$isArchiveThread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Grab the date you have, which is `$explosion[3]`
- convert it to a timestamp, with `strtotime($explosion[3])`

Then you have an integer value, you can compare anything with

Or if you are completely lazy like me, use something like **Carbon** where you can run quick date manipulations/comparisons https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: Using Carbon or DateTime doesn't mean that you are lazy.. it means that you are doing it right

Comment: I *think* this worked. Updated my scripts and am running it now... It'll take a while to process a few thousand files and insert 'em all into the DB, but I'll be sure to come back and Accept your answer if it worked. I don't normally work with PHP; dealing with dates seems far more difficult than it should. At least, out of the box it is.